# Javascript apply or call used on charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, browser, scope, call, this

The premise: what the correct charCodeAt(i : Int) performance would look like:

```
"test".charCodeAt(0)
116
"test".charCodeAt(1)
101
"test".charCodeAt(2)
115
"test".charCodeAt(3)
116
"test".charCodeAt(4)
NaN
```

**and here what happens when when using call or apply:**

```
>"test".charCodeAt.apply(this, [0,1,2,3])
91
//that's fine, except for 91!
"test".charCodeAt.call(this,0)
91
"test".charCodeAt.call(this,4)
101
"test".charCodeAt.call(this,5)
99
"test".charCodeAt.call(this,50)
NaN
"test".charCodeAt.call(this,6)
116
"test".charCodeAt.call(this,8)
68

x = "test".charCodeAt
function charCodeAt() { [native code] }
x.call(x,0)
102
```

The arguments are passed correctly. It is about the scope of which is passed with the first argument of call or apply and changes  the valueOf from the *this* pointer.

I am not really sure what happened, and couldn't reproduce the behaviour in a new console window (Chrome v15):

```
x = "test"
"test"

"".charCodeAt.call(this.x,0)
116
OK.
```

As to the question: When the scope is not specified with *this.x* but only *x* -in this exampl-e,  can *odd behaviour* result owing to the scope-resolution of the JS interpreter?
Did someone encounter similar cases with strange scope-conflicts?

Comment: I just looked at your blog and you are extending the prototype of host objects. This is often dangerous. For `String` it's safe though. But please never ever try doing it for `Array` or `Object`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster well, it may not be something everybody likes to do, but some libraries (Functional, Prototype) use the extension of native objects as a fundamental architectural approach.

Answer (score 6):

In all those calls like:

```
"test".charCodeAt.call(this, 0);
```

the value of `this` is likely to be `window`, not any string value.  Try this:

```
var string = "test";
string.charCodeAt.call(string, 0);
```

If you pass in something bogus for `this`, you can't expect it to work properly :-)  The reason it works when you define a variable "x" and then refer to "this.x" is, again, that `this` is `window`, so "this.x" is the same as "window.x", which will get you your variable.

Comment: @Joey but it's just a variable name; "String" is a pre-defined constructor name.

Comment: `String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(string, 0)` would be most appropriate.

Comment: @ThiefMaster yes that's true, if it's desired to isolate the function for some reason it's best to get it off the prototype object directly. I was trying to stay parallel with the original question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is `window` in your case and `window.toString() === "[object Window]"`.
So you are working with that string.

If you want the `charCodeAt` function better use `var foo = String.prototype.charCodeAt;` and then call it on some string: `foo.call('meow', 0)`

Comment: `>this.toString()
"[object DOMWindow]"`

Perfect, that answers why the string's accessible indexes were roughtly 20!